# Jackrabbit Configured class org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.OraclePersistenceManager does not contain a property named tableSpace

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, jackrabbit, jcr

I try to use a Jackrabbit with Oracle DB as Persistence Layer. Therefore I installed Jackrabbit on a Tomcat 6 Server (local). The Database runs in a virtual machine.
After installing the war file from the Jackrabbits project page I used the default installation mechanism. After that I changed the configuration (repository.xml) and deleted all Folders (workspaces and repository). So my Jackrabbit folder only contains the repositry.xml and bootstrap.properties.

Here my reporitory.xml

```
<Repository>
    <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.db.OracleFileSystem">
        <param name="driver" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
        <param name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"/>
        <param name="user" value="JCR" />
        <param name="password" value="test"/>
        <param name="schema" value="oracle"/>
    </FileSystem>
    <DataStore class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.db.DbDataStore">
        <param name="driver" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
        <param name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"/>
        <param name="user" value="JCR" />
        <param name="password" value="test"/>
    </DataStore>
    <Security appName="Jackrabbit">
        <SecurityManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.DefaultSecurityManager" workspaceName="security">
        </SecurityManager>
        <AccessManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.DefaultAccessManager">
        </AccessManager>

        <LoginModule class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.authentication.DefaultLoginModule">
           <param name="anonymousId" value="anonymous"/>
           <param name="adminId" value="admin"/>
        </LoginModule>
    </Security>

    <Workspaces rootPath="${rep.home}/workspaces" defaultWorkspace="default"/>
    <Workspace name="${wsp.name}">
        <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.db.OracleFileSystem">
            <param name="driver" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
            <param name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"/>
            <param name="user" value="JCR" />
            <param name="password" value="test"/>
            <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="${wsp.home}_"/>
        </FileSystem>
        <PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.OraclePersistenceManager">
            <param name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"/>
            <param name="user" value="JCR" />
            <param name="password" value="test"/>
            <param name="tableSpace" value=""/>
            <param name="externalBLOBs" value="false"/>
            <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="${wsp.home}_"/>  
        </PersistenceManager>
        <SearchIndex class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex">
            <param name="path" value="${wsp.home}/index"/>
            <param name="supportHighlighting" value="true"/>
        </SearchIndex>
    </Workspace>

    <Versioning rootPath="${rep.home}/version">
        <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.db.OracleFileSystem">
            <param name="driver" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
            <param name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"/>
            <param name="user" value="JCR" />
            <param name="password" value="test"/>
        </FileSystem>
        <PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.OraclePersistenceManager">
            <param name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"/>
            <param name="user" value="JCR" />
            <param name="password" value="test"/>
            <param name="tableSpace" value=""/>
            <param name="externalBLOBs" value="false"/>
            <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="version_"/>
        </PersistenceManager>
    </Versioning>

    <SearchIndex class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex">
        <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/repository/index"/>
        <param name="supportHighlighting" value="true"/>
    </SearchIndex>
</Repository>
```

With this configuration I get the following exception at the startup of tomcat:

```
javax.jcr.RepositoryException: Cannot instantiate persistence manager org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.OraclePersistenceManager
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.createPersistenceManager(RepositoryImpl.java:1353) [jackrabbit-core-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.createVersionManager(RepositoryImpl.java:486) [jackrabbit-core-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.<init>(RepositoryImpl.java:311) [jackrabbit-core-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.create(RepositoryImpl.java:589) [jackrabbit-core-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.j2ee.RepositoryStartupServlet.createRepository(RepositoryStartupServlet.java:445) [RepositoryStartupServlet.class:na]
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.j2ee.RepositoryStartupServlet.initRepository(RepositoryStartupServlet.java:413) [RepositoryStartupServlet.class:na]
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.j2ee.RepositoryStartupServlet.startup(RepositoryStartupServlet.java:242) [RepositoryStartupServlet.class:na]
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.j2ee.RepositoryStartupServlet.init(RepositoryStartupServlet.java:215) [RepositoryStartupServlet.class:na]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241) [servlet-api-2.5.jar:2.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1206) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1026) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4421) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4734) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_33]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_33]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_33]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_33]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289) [bootstrap.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414) [bootstrap.jar:6.0.35]
Caused by: org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.ConfigurationException: Configured class org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.OraclePersistenceManager does not contain a property named tableSpace
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.BeanConfig.newInstance(BeanConfig.java:206) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.createPersistenceManager(RepositoryImpl.java:1340) [jackrabbit-core-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
2012-08-23 16:14:41.657 INFO  [main] RepositoryImpl.java:1060          Shutting down repository...
2012-08-23 16:14:41.662 INFO  [main] RepositoryImpl.java:1165          Repository has been shutdown
2012-08-23 16:14:41.663 ERROR [main] RepositoryStartupServlet.java:250 RepositoryStartupServlet initializing failed: org.apache.jackrabbit.j2ee.ServletExceptionWithCause: Error while creating repository
org.apache.jackrabbit.j2ee.ServletExceptionWithCause: Error while creating repository
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.j2ee.RepositoryStartupServlet.initRepository(RepositoryStartupServlet.java:415) [RepositoryStartupServlet.class:na]
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.j2ee.RepositoryStartupServlet.startup(RepositoryStartupServlet.java:242) [RepositoryStartupServlet.class:na]
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.j2ee.RepositoryStartupServlet.init(RepositoryStartupServlet.java:215) [RepositoryStartupServlet.class:na]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241) [servlet-api-2.5.jar:2.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1206) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1026) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4421) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4734) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595) [catalina.jar:6.0.35]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_33]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_33]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_33]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_33]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289) [bootstrap.jar:6.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414) [bootstrap.jar:6.0.35]
Caused by: javax.jcr.RepositoryException: Cannot instantiate persistence manager org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.OraclePersistenceManager
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.createPersistenceManager(RepositoryImpl.java:1353) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.createVersionManager(RepositoryImpl.java:486) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.<init>(RepositoryImpl.java:311) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.create(RepositoryImpl.java:589) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.j2ee.RepositoryStartupServlet.createRepository(RepositoryStartupServlet.java:445) [RepositoryStartupServlet.class:na]
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.j2ee.RepositoryStartupServlet.initRepository(RepositoryStartupServlet.java:413) [RepositoryStartupServlet.class:na]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.ConfigurationException: Configured class org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.OraclePersistenceManager does not contain a property named tableSpace
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.BeanConfig.newInstance(BeanConfig.java:206) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.createPersistenceManager(RepositoryImpl.java:1340) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Jackrabbit 2.4.2 the parameter is called 'tablespace'. So it should be in lowercase. That's why you get the error message.

See also:

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jackrabbit/tags/2.4.2/jackrabbit-core/src/main/java/org/apache/jackrabbit/core/persistence/pool/OraclePersistenceManager.java